# Not able to upload data to cosmos using Azure UI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to upload the data to cosmos DB (NoSQL API).
Here is my Partition key logic for the Table

partition key : /x_id/location/name
unique keys : [/source, /type]

The JSON file I want to upload is

```
[
  {
    "x_id": "1",
    "type": "ROLL",
    "location": "10",
    "source": "A",
    "event_name": "B"
  },
  {
    "x_id": "2",
    "type": "ROLL",
    "location": "11",
    "source": "C",
    "event_name": "D"
  }
]
```

It's giving me the below error for saving the data

```
Error bulk creating items for container table_name:
 Cannot use the 'in' operator to search for 'location' in 1
```

But when I add single items to the same container it's working fine, but when doing bulk upload it starts giving the above error.

Option used for bulk upload : `Upload Item`
[image]

Error :
[image]

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: for uploading json I am using `Upload Items` option which will ask for Json file to be attached

Comment: can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshot of option & error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to create hierarchical partition key in cosmos db,
  `/x_id/location/name` click  `Add hierarchical partition key` for adding each key in order. Since there is no column named `name` in the sample document shared, I replaced that with `event_name`.

[image]

- After creating partition key as in above image, items got uploaded without any error.

[image]

Comment: Can we create this using Terraform scripts as I don't see any options to do this ?

Comment: Are you asking for partition keys?

Comment: partition Keys cannot be changed for the container. While creating new container, create the partition key as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes I am asking when creating the container using terraform scripts can I create hierarchical partition keys ?

Comment: I tried this in UI only

Comment: I followed these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep#azure-portal